# Combine CSS Selectors

Tags: css

How would I combine the following two CSS Selectors?

```
.requestsTable tr:hover {
    background-color: #DCF4F2;
}
.requestsTable tr:hover select {
    background-color: #DCF4F2;
}
```

Also, I would appreciate suggestions for improving the question so it comes up in search results. My searches for a solution didn't come up with anything useful.

Comment: I think you're looking for "Selector Grouping"

Comment: @Brain - thanks. You're right and the accepted answer worked. I'm not sure why the question was downvoted even though I clearly stated that I didn't know how to search for the answer or even properly ask the question. "Selector Grouping" was the key to finding the answer in Google.

Comment: Don't take it personal, think of it as encouragement of sorts, read **[about asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** and you'll avoid that in the future. Just a point of advice, if you can't find the perfect search query, widen the search and drill down into the content. Like "CSS Selector basics" which the first result demonstrates grouping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "combine". Do you mean share the same CSS properties between 2 selectors?

```
.requestsTable tr:hover,
.requestsTable tr:hover select {
    background-color: #DCF4F2;
}
```